# Correctly moving an SpriteKit Node around a scene with mouse input

Tags: swift, macos, sprite-kit, scenekit, sknode

I have an instance of an `SKScene` that I'm using as an overlay view on top of an `SCNView` in my macOS project. I'm currently working on trying to move an `SKNode` around the Sprite-Kit scene. I have a gesture recognizer set up to detect if a hit-test occurred for moving the `SCNodes` around the `SCNView` that works well for those nodes:

```
//Handle press to select
@objc func handleTap(gestureRecognize:NSGestureRecognizer){
    let point = gestureRecognize.location(in: self.scnView)
    let hits = self.scnView.hitTest(point, options: nil)

    deselectObject() //empty tap

    for hit in hits{
        if hit.node != grid_node{
            selectObject(tappedNode: hit.node)
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I'm selecting an `SKNode`, the hit test result comes back as 0 since it's only tracking things in the SKscene, not the overlay scene...so, I tried modifying the hit test code like so:

```
    let hits = self.scnView.overlaySKScene?.view?.hitTest(point)
```

But, then got the following error:

```
    for hit in hits{
        if hit.node != grid_node{
            selectObject(tappedNode: hit.node)
        }
    }
```

So, my next thought was to use mouse events to track what the selected `SKNode` is, and drag it around the overlay scene, like so:

```
override func mouseMoved(with event: NSEvent) {
    // Get mouse position in scene coordinates
    let location = event.location(in: self.overlayScene)
    selectedSKNode?.position = location
}

override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    // Get mouse position in scene coordinates
    let location = event.location(in: self.overlayScene)
    // Get node at mouse position
    selectedSKNode? = self.overlayScene.atPoint(location)
    selectedSKNode?.position = location
}

override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
    // Get mouse position in scene coordinates
    let location = event.location(in: self.overlayScene)
    selectedSKNode?.position = location
}
```

However, it seems as though the `mouseDown` and `mouseUp` methods aren't being called - only the `mouseMoved` method is.

So, I guess my question is in a few different parts:

1) Why isn't `mouseDown` or `mouseUp` being called?
2) Why would I be getting the `Type 'NSView?' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'` error after modifying my hittest code?
3) Is there someway to detect what node is detected in a scene, regardless of it's an `SCNode` or an `SKNode`?

Comment: You don't use the HitTest in Sprite Kit.  "Is there someway to detect what node is detected in a scene"  Use the name property of a node.  Sorry...  But that's basics.

Comment: No.  Don't use NSGestureRecognizer.  You don't use it in order to make the HistTest.